# Leaking goroutines, typically have three times as many running as I want

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm trying to make a web scraper, which can run a decent number (many thousands) of http queries per minute. The actual querying is fine but to speed up the process. I'm trying to make it concurrent. Initially I spawned a goroutine for each request but I ran out of file descriptors so after some googling I decided to use a semaphore to limit the number of concurrent goroutines.

Only I can't get this to work.

I've tried moving bits of code around but I always have the same issue: I have roughly three times as many goroutines running as I want

This is the only method I have that spawns goroutines. I limited the goroutines to 80. In my benchmarks I run this against a slice of 10000 URLs and it tends to hover at about 242 concurrent goroutines in flight, but then it suddenly goes up to almost double this and then back down to 242.

I get the same behaviour if I change the concurrent value from 80 - it usually hovers at just over three times the number of goroutines and sometimes spikes to around double that and I have no idea why.

```
func (B BrandScraper) ScrapeUrls(URLs ...string) []scrapeResponse {
    concurrent := 80
    semaphoreChan := make(chan struct{}, concurrent)
    scrapeResults := make([]scrapeResponse, len(URLs))
    for _, URL := range URLs {
        semaphoreChan <- struct{}{}
        go func(URL string) {
            defer func() {
                <-semaphoreChan
            }()
            scrapeResults = append(scrapeResults,
                B.getIndividualScrape(URL))
            fmt.Printf("#goroutines: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        }(URL)
    }
    return scrapeResults
}
```

I'm expecting it to be constantly at 80 goroutines - or at least constant.

This happens when I run it from a benchmarking test or when i run it from the main function.

Thanks very much for any tips!

EDIT

```
getIndividualScrape
```

calls another function:

```
func (B BrandScraper) doGetRequest(URL string) io.Reader {
    resp, err := http.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()
    return bytes.NewReader(body)
}
```

which obviously does an HTTP request. Could this be leaking goroutines? I thought since I'd closed the `resp.Body` I'd have covered that but maybe not?

Comment: There are other background goroutines spawned by the runtime and by functionality you're using from the standard library. Is there actually a problem?

Comment: @Adrian The problem is really the random spikes, if it was consistently three times as high as I 'want' then that would be fine (ish)

Comment: But why do you want that? Unless you're hitting a memory or CPU constraint, it seems like you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: I assume `getIndividualScrape` is making some sort of http request? Which of course can start multiple goroutines of its own. The problem is not in this part of the code, but in your handling of the http client.

Comment: The initial issue was that I was hitting a file descriptor limit because of the HTTP requests the goroutines trigger. But now I'd also like to know why the number is so variable.

Comment: @JimB yeah, exactly it makes an HTTP request. I get that it can trigger more goroutines, but do you know why the number of goroutines it triggers might not be constant?

Comment: @dircrys: I can't say without the code, but chances are idle connections have something to do with it.

Comment: @JimB, I just updated my answer to include the method which sends the http request - I thought it would be okay since I closed the resp.body though?

Comment: To start, nothing is "leaking" goroutines, just because there's a spike. If it's possible to be connecting to the same host repeatedly and concurrently, your default transport is only going to store a max of 2 idle conns per host, which may be causing you to open and close connections too quickly. The DeafultTransport also will hold up to 100 idle conns (which is at least 200 goroutines) until they are closed by the server.

Comment: Okay, that sounds okay then? Do you know if there's anything I can do to stop the variance in active goroutines or am I just going to have to accept it?

Comment: Set `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` to your expected max concurrency per-host? Set `MaxConnsPerHost` to limit concurrency to a host (80 connections to a single host isn't going to gain you anything). Lower `IdleConnTimeout` to close the connections sooner? Make sure your overall concurrency is sensible? (again 80 concurrent connections may not be useful). Lower timeouts to bypass unresponsive hosts more quickly? Only you can make these decisions, based on your systems, your data, etc.

Comment: nitpick, but don't use http.Get 
https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779
You can end up with your connections being seized by a bad host keeping go-routines out of play and locking up your resources.